# Projecting Neo4j Graphs Using Cypher and GDS

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using the following query to create in memory graph:

```
CALL gds.graph.project.cypher(
'testgraph2', 
'MATCH (n:Function) RETURN id(n) AS id',
'MATCH (n:Function)-[r:CALLS]->(m:Function) RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target')
```

However, I do not want to take all the nodes, instead I want to include only the nodes that have any incoming or outcoming edges. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
MATCH (n:Function) RETURN id(n) AS id
```

use this:

```
MATCH (n:Function) WHERE EXISTS((n)--()) RETURN id(n) AS id
```